# ActiveMQ WebSocket - Connection to STOMP failed : java.io.IOException

Tags: logging, websocket, log4j, jms, activemq-classic

Am trying a very simple program to use WebSocket in Active MQ 5.11.1

WebSocket is enabled in Active MQ as below

```
<transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

This is my client code

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:61614');

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});

ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

When I run this node app, i get the above warning and the message is not reaching the client

```
 WARN | Transport Connection to: StompSocket_431405783 failed: java.io.IOExcepti
on
```

Some light on this??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to just connect and send any old thing over to ActiveMQ, at least in the examples you've given.  This of course will never work as you need to communicate using the correct protocol (currently STOMP and MQTT are supported).

There are several implementations out there for client side communication inside Node for STOMP based messaging.  One such library would be [Stomp.js](http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/).

Comment: Hey .. I even tried with Stomp.js. Same error. Stomp.js , node-stomp.. both the libraries!

Comment: You'd need to update your question with a more meaningful example then as the current one just won't work.

Comment: Frankly. its very simple example..I push some data to active mq and i want the data to be received in one of these protocols ws:// or stomp://.. currently i can receive messages only in jms consumer. i want to receive in a consumer that is using websocket or stomp protocol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a bit late for an answer, I'm sorry, but... Could be this way?

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://domainOrip:61614', 'stomp');

//Notify connection
ws.onopen = function (){
    ws.send('CONNECT\n\n\0');

//Suscription
    ws.send('SUBSCRIBE\ndestination:/topic/topicA\nack:auto\nactivemq.retroactive:true\n\n\0');
};

//Listener
ws.onmessage = function (e) { ... };
```

At least, works for me with your configuration.